# Is constructor called if nothrow new return nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, new-operator, nothrow

If I use `new` and get `std::bad_alloc` compiler do not call constructor because of exception. But how does it works with the `nothrow new` cause we get pointer in every case? Is there special paragraph in standard for this case?

Comment: It just returns ```nullptr```, and obviously no object is created.

Comment: It would be physically impossible to call the constructor without having a region of storage into which to place the object.

Comment: _"...5-8) non-null pointer to suitably aligned memory of size at least size, __or null pointer on allocation failure__..."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: ```new``` does two things, calls ```malloc``` to "take the place" and then constructs object in that place, if the first one is already failed, there is no option/reason to do the second, so constructor won't be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **[expr.new]/16** ... if the allocation function returns null, initialization shall not be done, the deallocation function shall not be called, and the value of the *new-expression* shall be null.